# Linking the Document Library to the Menu - Site team Theme

Tags: sharepoint-online, json, json-formatting, team-sites, theme

I'm trying to add a theme for a team site. New theme i want add by Json and power shell. I have limitations to test my solution I need to ask someone to upload. The new theme should change the structure of the site in the following ways.

Delete from navigation on the left side:

- Conversations
- Documents
- Pages
- Site contents
- Project
- Notebook

Add to navigation on the left side
[image]

1. Client Documents (type: document library, after click on the menu, a list of "General files" should appear)

1a) Opportunities(type: document library, sub link of Client Documents)
1b) Project(type: document library, sub link of Client Documents)

I'm doing this for the 1st time and can't test it in small steps .  My main problem is to imagine if my Json structure will create such structure as I described. I was using the documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-json-schema Unfortunately I don't know how to connect document library to make it look like "Client Documents" is a parent of "Opportunities" and "Project" I think I should use something with "parentDisplayName" but I don't know if I can use it for createSPList ?

```
    {
    "verb": "removeNavLink",
    "displayName": "Conversations",
    "isWebRelative": true
},
{
    "verb": "removeNavLink",
    "displayName": "Documents",
    "isWebRelative": true
},
{
    "verb": "removeNavLink",
    "displayName": "Pages",
    "isWebRelative": true
},
{
    "verb": "removeNavLink",
    "displayName": "Site contents",
    "isWebRelative": true
},
{
    "verb": "removeNavLink",
    "displayName": "Project",
    "isWebRelative": true
},
{
    "verb": "removeNavLink",
    "displayName": "Notebook",
    "isWebRelative": true
},
{
    "verb": "createSPList",
    "listName": "Client Documents",
    "templateType": 101
  },
  {
    "verb": "createSPList",
    "listName": "Opportunities",
    "templateType": 101
  },
  {
    "verb": "createSPList",
    "listName": "Project",
    "templateType": 101

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `addNavLink` sub action on `createSPList` for Client Documents, this should create a link to Client Documents in the quick launch. After this action, use `createSPList` to create the other two libraries without using the `addNavLink` sub action (this would only create the links at the wrong level). For the last two actions, use the `addNavLink` action to create links for the Opportunities and Projects libraries using the `parentDisplayName` property to specify that these links should be children of the Client Documents link.

**Update:** You will need to set the `navComponent` property in your `removeNavLink` action to remove the links from your quick launch. More information can be found in the schema:

[JSON Schema for SiteScript Extensions](https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/site-design-script-actions.schema.json)

Comment: Thank you, do you know why this code does not remove my default fields in team, site ?    
 {
    "verb": "removeNavLink",
    "displayName": "Documents",
    "isWebRelative": true
},

Comment: I have updated the answer to include guidance regarding the removeNavLink action. If the answer is helpful, please let the community know by marking this as the answer.